# Aligning proof rules

Tags: alignment, logic, proof-package

The following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{float} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}  
            \infer[\textnormal{axiom} \, C]
            { C }
            {  } 
            \vspace{5pt}
            \infer[\textnormal{assume} \, L]
            { L \lor \lnot L }
            {  } 
            \vspace{5pt}        
            \infer[\textnormal{subst} \, s]
            { C[s] }
            { C }               

            
            \infer[\textnormal{resolve} \, L]
            { C \lor D }
            { L \lor C \quad \lnot L \lor D }
            \vspace{5pt}
            \infer[\textnormal{refl} \; t]
            { t = t }
            {  }
            \vspace{5pt}
            \infer[\textnormal{equality} \, L \, p \, t]
            { \lnot (s = t) \lor \lnot L \lor L' }
            {  }
    
    \caption{Current rules in the Metis prover}
    \label{fig:move-definition}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image]

How can I align all the horizontal rules to the right?

Comment: Where the `\infer` command defined?

Comment: @Bernard in the proof package

Comment: Yesterday you have delete your question :-( :-(...I suggest again to use ebproof package.

Comment: @Sebastiano, sorry, I actually found a solution by myself, and the help that you posted wasn't actually solving my issue

Comment: Is it `proof.sty` from the `lkproof` latex package?

Comment: @Bernard I just need to use \usepackage{proof} command

Comment: by the way i'm happy if this can be done using other packages

Comment: The problem is that on CTAN there's no proof latex package.

Comment: @Bernard oh, then how can I find out which .sty is installed?

Comment: Googling for proof.sty, I've found this page/site, which maybe where it comes from : [LaTeX for Logicians](https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/ndexamples/proofsty.html#commands)

Comment: By 'horizontal rules' do you mean the lines marking inferences or the justifications for those inferences? To take a wild guess, I'd say IEEEtran is responsible for the weird result here. (Does it set all maths left?) To get a reasonable result you need to undo that, but that wouldn't align everything right. Aligning everything right would be as bad as aligning everything left. At least, in the kind of proof system this package seems designed for, it would be. So I'm confused. I don't see how this could make sense right *or* left aligned :(.